# Packaging rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application that I'm trying to use on other machines that do not have ruby, rails, or bundler installed. Is there a way I can zip up the rails application, the ruby environment and all its gems / dependencies? I'd like to be able to just send the zipped file to a computer without ruby and be able to run the application without having to install ruby, rails, bundler and all the gems in the rails app.

I've tried [traveling-ruby](https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby/issues), but it just packages ruby and not rails or bundler.

Edit: For clarification, the app is an internal tool for work. We would rather not deploy the app to a server, but rather just share the whole package with computers that may or may not have the dependencies installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider [Docker](https://www.docker.com) to prepare a "package" of self sufficient environment for your application. This way you will be able to send it to another machine and run without problems. You can use those containers for development purposes only. There is no requirement to deploy them into a server.

Comment: Oh, I always thought of Docker of something to be hosted. I could use Docker to package everything I need and send it as a docker file?

Comment: You can create a Dockerfile to perform all necessary steps to build your container or you can just setup a basic environment with it, than do the rest manually in the container and save a snapshot at the end. Check out documentation and getting started section.

Comment: @VincentLe is it helpful?